# How can I tell which console opened the script?

Tags: python, encoding, console

I tried to write a simple logging script, which asks for text input and then saves the input along with a date and time into a new text file (or appends it to an existing one). The thing is, the IDLE GUI console (or what is it called) uses my default locale encoding (Windows 1250), but when I launch the script by just executing it from the File explorer, it opens in the default Win shell, which uses CP852 encoding. I already handled that by converting the input to unicode and than to cp1250 before writing the output, but what if I wanted to use both these consoles? Is there a way to tell them from each other? Maybe add one conditional which would convert the string using cp852 if it's an input from Win Shell and cp1250 if not?

Sorry if the post is too complicated, I am running 32bit Python 2.7.5 on Windows 7 64bit with Czech localisation.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-

import time
import datetime

ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print u'It is %s right now. What\'s up?' %st

string = unicode(raw_input(), 'cp852')

string_output = string.encode('cp1250', 'replace')

with open('log_2.txt', 'a') as log:
    log.write(st+'\n')
    log.write(string_output+'\n\n')

raw_input('Press Enter to exit')
```

Thanks for any advice on the topic.

Comment: Consider using `locale.getpreferredencoding()` for the log file encoding, which makes your code cross-platform and portable to different locales. `io.open` defaults to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following to get the encoding:

- sys.stdout.encoding will give you the encoding for the standard output
- sys.stdin.encoding will give you the encoding for the standard input.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hoped there is something handy like this, I just wasn't able to find it.